# Does traverse List generated by List.addAll produce ConcurrentModificationException in Java?

Tags: java

Code post below produced `ConcurrentModificationException` ,  `newMR` is ensured not modified in the loop, `mkrs` is thread unsafely in concurrent environment. It is known that `List.addAll` is implemented by `System.arraycopy` which  is intrinsic method in JVM. Does traverse `List` generated by `List.addAll` produce `ConcurrentModificationException` in Java?

```
ArrayList<Foo> mkrs = mrm.getFooPush();
ArrayList<Foo> newMR = new ArrayList<Foo>(mkrs.size());
newMR.addAll(mkrs);
for (Foo mkr : newMR) {
    if (mkr != null && mkr instanceof PushRecommend) {
        PushRecommend pr = (PushRecommend) mkr;
        recommendList.add(new MayKnowMessage(pr));
    }
}
```

Post the exception stack trace happened on an Android machine. Note that `(ProGuard:433)` is the line where `for (Foo mkr : newMR)` written.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException:
java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:837)
NewFriendManager.void loadNewFriendMsg(boolean)(ProGuard:433)
NewFriendManager.void reloadNewFriendMsg()(ProGuard:308)
NewFriendManager.boolean handleMessage(android.os.Message)(ProGuard:144)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: In Java, `ArrayList` is not a thread-safe type. `Vector` is though and that's probably what you want to use instead.

Comment: Please post the complete exception stack trace. I doubt that's `ArrayList.addAll` which produces the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Don't use `Vector` prefer `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())` instead

Comment: this code should not produce CMEx unless you are iterating over recommendList while executing this code. post the exception stack trace.

Comment: newMR.addAll is definitely not throwing the exception. You could have used `ArrayList<Foo> newMR = new ArrayList<>(mkrs);` without needing addAll. Exception stack trace will tell you the exact line which is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newMR.addAll(mkrs);` iterates over `mkrs, mrm.getFooPush()`.
If that list is changed during the addAll, you get that message.

You need to have a concurrency safe list (inside getFooPush) or a better data structure. Like a **queue** if the messages are added at the end, and you are filtered (on PushRecommend) consuming from the front.

*Then there is no need to make a copy.*

As already mentioned, the original data structure could be made safe by `Collections.synchronizedList(list)`.

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) for `ArrayList.addAll` states:

> "The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress."

So consider this:

```
newMR.addAll(mkrs);
```

The `addAll` method is going to have to iterate the `mkrs` collection.

If `mkrs` is modified by another thread while you are calling `addAll(mkrs)`, then a CCME is possible if the type of `mkrs` is not a concurrent collection that allows simultaneous iteration and updates.